# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. C#

Tags: c#

im trying to make a script for automated, dynamic adjustment of thrusters to maintain the speed of a vehicle.

in case u want to know its for a game^^

well anyway it keeps getting me that index was out of range error.

**Heres my Code** i added comments to make it more clearly

```
List<IMyTerminalBlock> blocks = new List<IMyTerminalBlock>();

string ThrusterControl = "Thrusters.Forward";    //the name of my thrusters.
string CruiseControl = "AI.Computer";            //The name of the block running this code.
double setSpeed=0.250;                           //my desired speed (units/tick).  
double maxSpeed=3.000;                           //This script disengages thruster overrides while im are above this speed.
double checkSpeed=0.75;                          //Determines the acceptable speed range.  
double decelerationRate=0.9;                     //Thrust override reduction factor
float speedBoost=500;                            //Gives a boost when im not moving
float minThrust=125;                             //Minimum legal value of thrust override.
double x0,dx; 
double y0,dy; 
double z0,dz; 
double speed; 
float newThrust;

void Main(){

//Determine ship speed. 

GridTerminalSystem.SearchBlocksOfName(CruiseControl,blocks);
double x = Math.Round(blocks[0].GetPosition().GetDim(0),3);
double y = Math.Round(blocks[0].GetPosition().GetDim(1),3);
double z = Math.Round(blocks[0].GetPosition().GetDim(2),3);
dx=x-x0;dy=y-y0;dz=z-z0;x0=x;y0=y;z0=z;
    speed=Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz),5);
        blocks[0].SetCustomName(CruiseControl+":"+"\n"+"speed (units/tick) "+speed );

//Increase thrust override if im going too slow.

if(speed < setSpeed * checkSpeed){
GridTerminalSystem.SearchBlocksOfName(ThrusterControl, blocks);
    for(int i=0; i < blocks.Count;){
        blocks[0].GetActionWithName("IncreaseOverride").Apply(blocks[0]);
        i++;}

//Give an extra thrust boost if you're im not moving at all.

if(speed < setSpeed * 0.05){
    newThrust = (float)Math.Round(blocks[0].GetValueFloat("Override") + speedBoost,4);
    for(int i=0; i < blocks.Count;){
        blocks[i].SetValueFloat("Override", newThrust);
        i++;}
    }
}

//Slowly reduces thrust override if im going too fast.

if(speed > setSpeed / checkSpeed){
GridTerminalSystem.SearchBlocksOfName(ThrusterControl, blocks);
newThrust = (float)Math.Round(blocks[0].GetValueFloat("Override") * decelerationRate, 4);
if( newThrust > minThrust){    //Prevents this script from disabling the thruster override.
    for(int i=0; i < blocks.Count;){
        blocks[i].SetValueFloat("Override", newThrust); 
        i++;}
    }

//Reset thruster overrides if moving too fast. Allows inertial dampers to regain control of vehicle.

if(speed > maxSpeed){
    for(int i=0; i < blocks.Count;){
        blocks[i].SetValueFloat("Override", 0);
        i++;}
    }
}

}
```

can someone correct my code please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which programming language is this? Please add a tag. And perhaps this question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would have edited the question and added a language tag. But I cannot decide whether it is c# or c++ :) ``Math.Round()`` makes me tend towards c#.

Comment: It's definitely not a fit for CR as long as it has issues. Codereview is about improving fully functional code. Not fixing errors.

Comment: Btw: Tried to add c# tag but cannot update my edit (funny error: Question already exists)... While I should have edit privileges.

Comment: ye cant edit it for the same reason. sry. 
its c#

Comment: Why do you do `blocks[0].GetActionWithName("IncreaseOverride").Apply(blocks[0]);` in loop?

Comment: i dunno if i get the question right. like the comment above that loop say´s its for increasing the acceleration.
so the loop has to take that ingame action "increaseOverride" if my speed is lower than wanted.

Comment: Can you verify if the item count of object `blocks` is greater than zero. You have used `blocks[0]` without checking if it has any item at index zero or not.

Comment: it is greater that zero.


i found the problem 

i got more than one timer available for that script.

Comment: wait no. the units/tick valor is way to high i cant find out how i should solve that

Comment: Does `GridTerminalSystem.SearchBlocksOfName(CruiseControl,blocks);` populate the blocks list at all? It looks like the `blocks` list is never populated with anything, and yet, you try to edit the first item, which does not exist.

Comment: Please show the implementation of `GridTerminalSystem.SearchBlocksOfName`.

Comment: its hard to explain mh. the programmable block is attached to the vehicle and the block knows every item on the vehicle. if namend correctly they can used.  u know what i mean?

crusise control is for exaple the name of the programming block

Comment: `speed=Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz),5);` 

gives me a result over 100000 steadily increasing.  may i did smth wrong with that?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having someone correct your code, wouldn't it be nice to understand exactly what's going on?

This exception is quite easy to debug. Visual Studio will stop execution where it occurs, and highlight the exact line. While this line is highlighted, you can mouse-over your variables and see their values to:

- Inspect the collection, and the number of items in it
- Inspect the variable that holds the index which is causing the problem

[image: Debugger]

The index variable will then either be less than 0 or greater or equal to the number of items in the collection.

With that information, you might be able to solve the issue yourself, but if not, you'll be able to ask a totally different question on SO.

**EDIT:**

If you're unable to debug this properly, you can always do a range check yourself, ie:

```
public void MyFunction()
{
    for (int i = ...)
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= blocks.Count)
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"error.log", "Error in MyFunction(), i = " + i + ", blocks.Count = " + blocks.Count);
        }

        blocks[i].SetValue(...);
    }
}
```

It takes alot more time, but it will at least give you insight in what's going on.

Comment: ty :)  but unfortunately i cant compile it by using visual studio cause the way its written it will only work in that game.

i would have to expant the program way to much to test it with visual studio.

Comment: You could then either mock the game (make your own objects that pretend to be the game) and debug it, or simply log what's going on (see my edit)

Comment: make my own objects would be nearly impossible cause i need to consider the behaviour of every single one. would need an amazing amount of time^^

i dunno if the log will work within the game but i´ll try after i get back from work.